# How to display only records in a select field, which are in a certain storagePid in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tsconfig

Is it possible to configure this in .tsconfig or .typoscript files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the TCA you can configure [`foreign_table_where`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/10.4/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/selectSingle.html#foreign-table-where) for a select.
Here you can add a selection on special page IDs.
These IDs could be configured by a marker, e.g. `###PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID###` (A value you can set from Page TSconfig dynamically.)

---

EDIT:

let's see the example from the manual:

```
'select_single_3' => [
    'label' => 'select_single_3 static values, dividers, foreign_table_where',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'items' => [
            ['Static values', '--div--'],
            ['static -2', -2],
            ['static -1', -1],
            ['DB values', '--div--'],
        ],
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_styleguide_staticdata',
        'foreign_table_where' => 'AND {#tx_styleguide_staticdata}.{#value_1} LIKE \'%foo%\' ORDER BY uid',
        'foreign_table_prefix' => 'A prefix: ',
    ],
],
```

modifying the `foreign_table_where` to your needs:

```
'foreign_table_where' => 'AND {#tx_styleguide_staticdata}.{#pid} = ###PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID###',
```

and the definition for this marker would be:

```
TCEFORM.tx_myext_domin_model_record.select_single_3.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 22
```

in general:

```
TCEFORM.<table>.<field>.PAGE_TSCONFIG_ID = 22
```

Comment: Thank you, but would it also be possible without changing the TCA? For example when a certain field in a page record has a certain value? I tried `[page["certainField"] == "certain_value] [END] ` as condition in TypoScript for the value of persistence.storagePid but it did not work.

Comment: you need to consider the context when the TCA is evaluated. in general TCA is just an array definition in PHP. so you can insert any PHP statement. but when will it be evaluated? which page is 'current' when it is evaluated? it might be possible, but I would prefer a TSconfig configuration if it should be page dependent. (I already used a 'global' value set be extension configuration, which needs a BE-cache clearing after configuration change!)

Comment: Thank you, how could I only add records with a certain storagePid as items in a select field in tsconfig?

Comment: ??? in TSconfig there are no select fields. In TSconfig you can define some constant which can be used in the TCA ( e.g. in `foreign_table_where`) to have a special selection of records available on this page (or subpages). e.g.: select for records from a special page, or records with a special value.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to change the list of items in TCA type=select fields with tsconfig. Using the keepItems property, all items except those who are in the desired storagePid should be  removed. But how could I do that

Comment: no condition in TSconfig. just the page id where the options for the select are stored. In the TCA you add a where clause which selects only records from the page configured in the TSconfig.

Comment: I added an example to my answer.